# Converting AsyncTask to RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a project that fetches OneSignal notification and it works fine but I want to remove the AsyncTask and use RxJava instead. I've followed some examples but nothing worked out so far.

This is the AsyncTask implementation

```
NotificationDao mDAO;
List<Messages> mList = new ArrayList<>();
NotificationDatabase mDataBase;

mDataBase = NotificationDatabase.getInstance(this);
mDAO = mDataBase.notificationDao();


new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Messages>>() {

            @Override
            protected List<Messages> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                return mDAO.getNotificationList();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<Messages> messages) {
                mList.clear();
                mList.addAll(messages);
                mAdapter.setData(messages);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }.execute();
```

I get nullppinter exception here

```
mList.addAll(messages);
```

I'll appreciate some insight on how to do this properly

Comment: please add `rxjava` tag to your question. it will help others to find your question.

Comment: See this two links. I'm sure you will get the idea: 1) http://androidsrc.net/replace-android-asynctask-rxjava/  2) http://loopcupcakes.com/migrating-asynctask-to-rxjava/

Comment: I already saw these. Didn't seem to give me what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same scenario with your other question. Please make sure you study more about Rx implementations as this will help you solve these issues.

```
Single.fromCallable(new Callable<List<Messages>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Messages> call() throws Exception {
                return mDAO.getAllNotification();
            }
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSuccess(new Consumer<List<Messages>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(List<Messages> messages) throws Exception {
                        mList.clear();
                        mList.addAll(messages);
                        mAdapter.setData(messages);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                })
                .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

                    }
                })
                .subscribe();
```